# Applying syntax coloring to strings in plain text files in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Trying to find a way to apply syntax color schemes to individual strings of code snippets within plain text files.

Often within a workspace I have a text file or two with notes about things to do, ideas to explore, etc.  These notes frequently contain code examples, be it a javascript snippet, CSS concept, html string, etc.

Would be nice be able to highlight a string, right click and select type (html, css, js, etc) and have the default color syntax for that item applied to just that string.

Is there a method to do this built in to VSC or an extension available?

Answer (score 0):

---

## You Are Looking 4 Language & Grammar Contributions

---

##### About the Question:

> *There is a way to do it via extensions, and extensions are actually the only way. There is a whole bunch of features that allow a person to Highlight Syntax, and their are different ways of highlighting syntax, that are used for different things. Highlighting syntax can be a relatively straight forward process, however, it can also get quite complex. When highlighting syntax in VSCode, their are areas where you will use only VSCode Contributions and JSON files, their are areas where you will need to use the VSCode extension API, and then their are areas where the **TextMate API** begins to blend into, the VSCode extension API, the VSCode Extension Manifest, And the VSCode JSON Theme file. TextMate is where things get advanced. I will explain more below, where I will also post the links to several of the topics I just mentioned.*
>
> *Learning VSCode Syntax Highlighting definitely comes with a small learning curve. Its not a dreadful curve, but its notifiable, if that makes sense — it is also highly rewarding when you do learn it.*

### PART 1: Visual Studio Code's Extension Manifest

The **[Extension Manifest](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest)**  is basically a VSCode version of a **[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json)** file, and you can just think of the it as, "defining the core structure of your extension". The extension manifests aren't a bad gig. If you are doing something simple, like what you are asking for, you can just add what ever simple things you are doing to your **`contributes`** object without having to implement an entire Extension Framework, or multiple Extension API's that you don't really need.

#### Here is an example of a VSCode theme's Extension Manifest.

```
// package.json


// An actual Extension Manifest for a theme I am working on

{
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "description": "This is a theme blah blah blah",
  "version": "1.2.3", 

  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/W3Dojo/Uchigatana.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.57.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Themes"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "themes": [
      {
        "label": "Uchigatana",
        "uiTheme": "vs-dark",
        "path": "./themes/Uchigatana.json"
      },
      {
        "label": "Tachi",
        "uiTheme": "hc-black",
        "path": "./themes/Tachi.json"
      },
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.3.1"
  }
}
```

> ###### AUTHOR'S NOTE:
>
> *"The above is an actual extension manifest from a theme that I just happen to have open. I find real life examples are better than copying and pasting code from other sources."*

---

Do you see the **`"contributes":{ ect... }"`** property-object? Well, this property is at the heart of every extension, and any syntax highlighting that you do will be defined in here in one form, or another.

So here is where You will read about syntax highlighting further:

---

[SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTING (Official VSCode Website)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)

[CONTRIBUTES OBJECT (Official VSCode Website)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.grammars)

[EXTENSION MANIFEST (Official VSCode Website)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest)

[TextMate GRAMMARS (TextMate Official Website)](https://macromates.com/textmate/manual/snippets#grammar)

---

On a final note you will want to look at 3 different topics that will help you achieve what you are looking to do:

1. TextMate Grammar Contributes: "Grammar link is above"
2. [Language Definitions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.languages): "This is a link to an anchor on the contributions page, but this could be useful to you".
3. [TextMate Tokens & Scopes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-tokens-and-scopes): "This is a link to an anchor that is located on the same page as the syntax highlighting link, but this is a topic you want to read about."

---

###### Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for the extension creation info.  Does that mean there is no suitable extension available today?

Comment: If your looking for a GUI that edits text in the editor theirs nothing like that that I know of. If there was, it would require that the file type supports a rich text format. The way that syntax-highlighting works, or at least syntax highlighting as I understand the term, is through AST parsing, which VSCode uses text-mate for. What you are looking for is a word processor, with an extension for processing code. I use Google-Docs because I run the non GUI Server-Version of Debian, but Microsoft Office, is likely to have a better extension for highlighting code and such.

Comment: I couldn't imagine an editor ever supporting a rich text format, because of the extra data the text would have to carry, I would Imagine that such a feature would be very unpopular amongst some developers.

Comment: Thanks.  I really don't want to use a separate editor, was simply looking for a way colorize snippets in my notes to find them easier when scanning that note.  Want to keep it all in VCS.

Comment: You can see what the notebook has to offer that was released in May(2021) VSC v(1.57.1) might be along the lines of what your looking for. I haven't used it, but I know it was created to offer things that Editors don't typically offer. Best a luck Tom