VSC color syntax within PHP HEREDOC HTML strings
Some background:
I was going to ask some Q about issues I have been having with syntax coloring while editing HTML strings that are embedded as HEREDOC strings in PHP code, and found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093286/25412 answer that gives some very good pointers to how syntax coloring works in VSC.
Having read some of it, and understood (a significantly smaller) part of it I have the following Q:
I understand that HEREDOC strings are strings,and as such, it makes perfect sense for VSC to color them as such. However, in many (or at least some) cases, those HEREDOC strings represent code in some other language, which can be HTML, JS, CSS, and so on.
I thought it would be great if I could use the HEREDOC delimiter string to indicate what syntax coloring to apply to the content of the HEREDOC string.
Example:
consider php code like:
<?php
$somehtml=<<<DELIM_HTML
<b>text</b>
DELIM_HTML;

$jsvar=<<<DELIM_JS
var a='12';
DELIN_JS;

The idea would be that if the delimiter ends (or starts) with a language than its syntax sould be applied to the string. This is perfectly backward compatible and will be very helpful for people writing such mixed code.
Moving on to my Qs:
Is this something that someone already though of?
Does an extension that does this exist?
If not, how complicated would it be to write something like this?
Will someone that writes something like this need to re-implement the tokenization of PHP from zero (I hope not) or can this be some sort of a mix and match using existing syntax coloring extensions?

I was able to find the "Template Literal Editor" which is very helpful though is not exactly what I was looking for.

Well, It looks like my idea is actually already implemented (partly)
just use <<<HTML and it will use HTML color syntax for the code in the heredoc.
I do still think that it would be nice if i could customize the identifier and still be able to indicate what language syntax to use. but being able to use <<<HTML has drastically improved my DX.
